# How Do I Store A Value In Cypress For Later Use Within A Test?

Tags: javascript, cypress

**Problem:** I am testing whether one piece of information is exactly the same as it is somewhere else. I would like to know how to keep that first piece of information, and then use it later for comparison through Cypress assertions.

**Steps for extra clarity of problem:**

1. Visit one URL path
2. Use `cy.get()` to obtain an element in the HTML DOM
3. Visit the second URL path
4. Assert the first element against one in the current page, and ensure they are matching.

**Current Code Attempt:**

```
// After visiting the first URL, I look to store the display title:
    cy.get('[datacy="displayTitle"]').then((displayTitle) => cy.wrap(displayTitle).as('displayTitle'));

// I then go to the second url
    cy.visit("different url")

// My attempt at asserting the first element equals the second.
    cy.get("@displayTitle").then(title => {
        const titleText = cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .css-106jpu6 > .css-1j088rq > .MuiBox-root > button > .MuiTypography-root')
        expect(title).to.equal(titleText)
    })
```

**Error:**

`(uncaught exception)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayTitle')`

It looks like I cannot read the properties when wrapping the display title, to make the assertion. What am I doing incorrectly? Is wrapping the best approach here?

Comment: Does this question need improving? Help me update it.

Comment: Unfortunately as it stands your error is not reproducible. There is an error in the way you access `titltText` but it's not related to the error message, in fact nothing you show above will cause that error message. Are you able to provide a minimal, reproducible example? Or add a screenshot of the Cypress runner log?

Comment: I believe, Otto, the question has been changed enough now to create more understanding of the request. Please let me know if there is more information required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to use `cy.wrap()`, and access the value of the element. This removed my error.

Read about wrap in the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap).

**Step 1)** Wrap the first element you would like to use later, and use the `val()` method to target the value of the element:

`cy.get('element').then((el) => cy.wrap(el.val()).as('el'));`

**Step 2)** Navigate to your new page:

`cy.visit(url)`

**Step 3)** Compare the first value with the value on that page:

```
cy.get('secondElement').then((secondEl) => cy.wrap(secondEl.val()).as('secondEl'));
cy.get("@secondElement").then((secondElement) => cy.get("@el").should("contain", secondElement));
```

**Code Samples Altogether:**

```
cy.get('element').then((el) => cy.wrap(el.val()).as('el'));
cy.visit(url)
cy.get('secondElement').then((secondEl) => cy.wrap(secondEl.val()).as('secondEl'));
cy.get("@secondElement").then((secondElement) => cy.get("@el").should("contain", secondElement));
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the options already mentioned, there is also the option of using [Cypress environment variables](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables).

The use is very simple:

Set variable:

```
Cypress.env(ENV_NAME, yourVariable)
```

Read variable:

```
const yourVariable = Cypress.env(ENV_NAME)
```

Comment: How does this fix the test in the question?